R and ggplot with st_crop: map cropping does not work as wanted
I am trying to plot only a part of the world map, limited by a square with limits lon (-30, 90) and lat (30, 82). When I try to crop the map with sf_crop, it does not return the desired square when plotting with ggplot, even though i make sure the used world map has the "normal" crs with specifying crs = 4326.
I know I could probably introduce map limits with coord_sf, but I need an alternative solution. I would really appreciate any help.
I tried the following code that produces the described problem:
lapply(c("rnaturalearthdata", "sf", "ggplot2","dplyr"), require, character.only = TRUE)

world <- ne_coastline(scale = "small", returnclass = "sf") %>%
  st_transform(world, crs = 4326)
world_cropped <- st_crop(world, xmin = -30, xmax = 90, ymin = 30, ymax = 82)

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = world, fill = NA, color = "black")

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = world_cropped, fill = NA, color = "black")

First map, as expected
Second cropped map, did not cut a "square" as I expected, strange result
Highlighted (by hand) the map square I want to be shown approximatelly

When working with geographic coordinates (WGS84 / EPSG:4326), sf by default uses spherical geometry operations through s2. So your bounding box defined by 4 corners is not really a rectangle; as sides follow shortest paths between 2 points on a sphere, 2 sides running east-west become arcs when projected on a plane. We can visualize it by adding more points to "straight" edges of bbox with st_segmentize():
library(rnaturalearth)
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)

world <- ne_coastline(scale = "small") 
bb_wgs84 <-  
  st_bbox(c(xmin = -30, xmax = 90, ymin = 30, ymax = 82), crs = "WGS84") |> 
  st_as_sfc()

world_cropped <- st_crop(world, bb_wgs84)
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = st_segmentize(bb_wgs84, 1000), fill = "lightgreen", alpha = .2) +
  geom_sf(data = bb_wgs84, fill = NA, color = "darkgreen", linewidth = 1) +
  geom_sf(data = world_cropped, fill = NA)


Probably easiest workaround is switching s2 off for the crop operation so coordinates are treated as planar coordinates, which allows that rectangular cropping you are probably after.
sf_use_s2(use_s2 = FALSE)
#> Spherical geometry (s2) switched off

world_cropped <- st_crop(world, xmin = -30, xmax = 90, ymin = 30, ymax = 82)
#> although coordinates are longitude/latitude, st_intersection assumes that they
#> are planar
#> Warning: attribute variables are assumed to be spatially constant throughout
#> all geometries
sf_use_s2(use_s2 = TRUE)
#> Spherical geometry (s2) switched on

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = st_segmentize(bb_wgs84, 1000), fill = "lightgreen", alpha = .2) +
  geom_sf(data = bb_wgs84, fill = NA, color = "darkgreen", linewidth = 1) +
  geom_sf(data = world_cropped, fill = NA)


Created on 2024-07-09 with reprex v2.1.0

Thank you! The solution with: sf_use_s2(use_s2 = TRUE) provided by @margusl worked. Really nice answer, illustrates well how sf_crop works.

a small comment on the "2 of it's sides become arcs that follow shortest paths between 2 points on a sphere" part if I  may without sounding too nitpicky - technically all sides of the crop follow shortest paths (great circles). It's just that meridians already are great circles, while parallels almost never are (with the notable exception of the Equator). As if more confirmation was needed that geo is weird...

@JindraLacko , your additions are always welcome. I'm currently having trouble rephrasing it myself without making it more confusing, so hoping your comment remains :) . And you are also welcome to edit.
